# How can I print values passed to an EJS file using a nested for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

trying to print the values passed to the ejs file. but not able to prin

```
<%for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){%>
        
        <tr>
            <%for(header of heading){%>
                
                <td><%=data[i].header%></td>
            <%}%>
        </tr>
    <%}%>
```

Comment: Please show how you pass the data to the template